# Why is my uncompressed PNG pixel data inaccurate?

Tags: java, png, zlib

I am trying to inflate a PNG file's IDAT data using jzlib, and print out the R, G, B, and A values in hexadecimal. I have a program which works (no errors), but the values printed out appear incorrect.

My image is a 2x2 completely white PNG file with no compression (from Photoshop).

Here is my code:

```
import com.jcraft.jzlib.GZIPException;
import com.jcraft.jzlib.Inflater;
import com.jcraft.jzlib.JZlib;

import java.io.*;

public class main {

    private static final int imageWidth = 2;
    private static final int imageHeight = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pngPath = args[0];
        File pngFile = new File(pngPath);

        try {
            DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pngFile));
            byte[] data = new byte[8];
            stream.readFully(data); //Read PNG Header

            while (true) {
                data = new byte[4];
                stream.readFully(data); //Read Length
                int length = ((data[0] & 0xFF) << 24)
                        | ((data[1] & 0xFF) << 16)
                        | ((data[2] & 0xFF) << 8)
                        | (data[3] & 0xFF); //Byte array to int
                stream.readFully(data); //Read Name
                String name = new String(data); //Byte array to String
                if (name.equals("IDAT")) {
                    data = new byte[length];
                    stream.readFully(data); //Read Data

                    int maxInflateBuffer = 4 * (imageWidth + 1) * imageHeight;
                    byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[maxInflateBuffer];

                    long inflatedSize = inflate(data, outputBuffer, maxInflateBuffer);

                    int index = 0;
                    byte r, g, b, a;

                    for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
                        index++;
                        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
                            r = outputBuffer[index];
                            g = outputBuffer[index + 1];
                            b = outputBuffer[index + 2];
                            a = outputBuffer[index + 3];

                            System.out.println(byteToHex(r) + " : " + byteToHex(g) + " : " + byteToHex(b) + " : " + byteToHex(a));
                            System.out.println("------------------------");

                            index += 4;
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                } else { //Don't care about other chunks
                    data = new byte[length + 4]; //Data length + 4 byte CRC
                    stream.readFully(data); //Skip Data and CRC.
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static long inflate(byte[] data, byte[] outputBuffer, int maxInflateBuffer) throws GZIPException {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater(15);

        inflater.setInput(data, true);

        inflater.setOutput(outputBuffer);

        try {
            inflater.inflate(JZlib.Z_NO_COMPRESSION);
        } finally {
            inflater.inflateEnd();
        }

        return inflater.getTotalOut();
    }

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String byteToHex(byte b) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[2];
        int v = b & 0xFF;
        hexChars[0] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
}
```

And here is the output, in order of R : G : B : A...

```
FF : FF : FF : 00
------------------------
00 : 00 : 02 : 00
------------------------
00 : 00 : 00 : 00
------------------------
00 : 00 : 00 : 00
------------------------
```

My assumption is that it would look more like:

```
FF : FF : FF : FF
------------------------
FF : FF : FF : FF
------------------------
FF : FF : FF : FF
------------------------
FF : FF : FF : FF
------------------------
```

Why doesn't it? What is wrong? I have spent a while on this and can't figure it out.

Here is a link to the image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7kKX.png (Right click -> Save as)

**Edit:**

I tried using the inbuilt Java Inflater library as CoderNeji suggested in the comments:

```
private static long inflate(byte[] data, byte[] outputBuffer, int maxInflateBuffer) {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();

    inflater.setInput(data, 0, maxInflateBuffer);

    try {
        inflater.inflate(outputBuffer);
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return inflater.getTotalOut();
}
```

And got the same result. Also, using either method, a 2x2 black image gives this output:

```
00 : 00 : 00 : 00
------------------------
00 : 00 : 00 : 00
------------------------
00 : 00 : 00 : 00
------------------------
00 : 00 : 00 : 00
------------------------
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: i think in java FF FF FF FF is for black

Comment: also i would recommend using java inbuilt library for inflating the deflated data i.e java.util package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about the [row filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#9Filters). You skipped the first byte on printing and so you did not see the first one (and subsequently all other 'first bytes' per row, which is not a bad thing - except you did it too soon).
Also, you are printing an alpha channel output while the image does not have one. Contrary to what you state, the image is not RGBA, it is RGB, without the alpha. The line

```
index += 4;
```

should thus be

```
index += 3;
```

You might have noticed the errors by comparing the printed output size against what you got for `inflatedSize`. As it is, `inflatedSize` should be 14, and you printed 16 bytes of data (and also skipped 2 more).

The *actual* decompressed data, one line at a time, is

```
01 : FF FF FF : 00 00 00
02 : 00 00 00 : 00 00 00
```

The first number per line is the row filter, followed by 2 (width) * 3 (channels) pixel data entries.

These 2 row filters are Sub and Up, and applying them left to right, top to bottom, you get

```
FF FF FF : FF FF FF
FF FF FF : FF FF FF
```

which translates to "2x2 full white pixels", just as one expects.